# How to find quadratic equation roots with gradient descent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, equation

How to find quadratic equation roots with gradient descent? I wrote a code to find `argmin` of given equation but I can not understand how to find exactly roots.

```
# x**2 + 5 * x + 6 = 0   roots: -3, -2

def grad(x):
    return 2 * x + 5

def grad_desc():
    x_old = float('inf')
    epsilon = 0.000001
    lr = 0.01
    x_new = 0
    while abs(x_new - x_old) > epsilon:
        x_old = x_new
        x_new -= lr * grad(x_new)
    return x_new

x = grad_desc()
```

x - `argmin` of given equation. How can I now find roots approximately right. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: grad() should be "return (2 * x + 5)*(x**2 + 5 * x + 6)" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Solution_of_a_non-linear_system

Answer (score 0):

Have x_new start off as a small number > 0.

Right now it starts at 0, which causes an infinite loop